# Angular ui-router not loading external content on state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have started building a website using Angular, and have started to use ui-router along with ngAnimation for some sick animations! All was going well until I started adding external resources such as Facebook's Page Widget (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) and Google Maps API for some custom map styles.

## The Issue

I have the Facebook widget on the home page, and it loads fine when you first access the URL as can be seen below (Have to block the name of client, totally not just bad design...):

[image: Have to block the name of client]

Once I click on another page to load it in (using ui-view to dynamically bring in a view), for example contact view and go back to the home page (where the code is to display the widget), the widget will no longer load but will load the basic header tag that Facebook provide as can be seen below:

[image]

This also happens on the contact page when loading in Google Maps API. If I click on the contact page, there will just be a large white area on where the map should be, but if you had to actually refresh the page the map will load.

I am assuming that the issue is that the website is not able to send a request to either Facebook or Google when a view is loaded in, but can only happen when the page is actually refreshed or a new page load.

## My Code

Okay so I'll explain the basics of how my application works along with code. I am rather new with Angular so if I have terrible code, please let me know.

### Structure

This is a screen shot of my web apps structure. The main template file is index.html, and any view are within the views directory, which are loaded in using ui-router.

[image]

#### Main Angular applications code (app.js)

```
var app = angular.module('bmApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('header', {
        templateUrl: './assets/views/template.html',
    })
    .state('header.home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: './assets/views/home.html',
        controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .state('header.about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: './assets/views/about.html',
        controller: "AboutController"
    })
    .state('header.work', {
        url: '/work',
        templateUrl: './assets/views/work.html',
        controller: "WorkController"
    })
    .state('header.services', {
        url: '/services',
        templateUrl: './assets/views/services.html',
        controller: "ServicesController"
    })
    .state('header.contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: './assets/views/contact.html',
        controller: "ContactController"
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); //if no views are matched, just redirect back to home page.
})
```

I am using nested views to keep the header of the website static (not changing) and then loading in views under the header, with ngAnimate to make it look *cool*.

In my main template, index.html, I have a simple `<div ui-view></div>` to load in the view that is requested. I also have the required script to request Facebook's API just after the . My controllers do not actually currently have anything in them. I did have some vanilla JavaScript in some, but do not currently need it anymore. I also tried to wrap the code provided by Facebook in a function, and call it within the controller for the specific view but that just had the same results of having it within the body on the template (index.html) page.

Pulling my hair out at this, can't seem to find a solution. I hope I have explained my issue without missing out on anything. I appreciate any help you could give, would be so awesome.

**Edit: I should have probably mentioned that my main template is index.html, I then inject the view in to /views/template.html AND THEN inject it into index.html. Not too sure if this is best practice, but felt like it would work well (I don't think that is the issue).**

Comment: Do you use standard javascript or specific angular plugins ?

Comment: @Skahrz Yes, just standard JavaScript provided by Facebook and Google.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you only half of an answer, but maybe it will point you to right direction. I also struggled with Google API in SPA application once. I had the same issue - after entering the contact page, a white box appeared instead of map. The solution turned out to be simple - I just needed to *force* map reload, when I entered contact sheet. This function was attached as `onclick` event to contact page link:

```
function reloadGoogleMap() {
    if (counter == 0) {
        document.getElementById('google-map').src += '';
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I used the counter to make sure it happens only once - you won't need it probably. With Angular, you might need to make sure the reload happens after element is rendered. Maybe a simple directive would work, however I didn't test that:

```
angular.module('your_directives_module')
    .directive('mapLoaded', [mapLoadedDirective]);

function mapLoadedDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('load', function (event) {
                // Force reload
                elem.src += '';
            });
        }
    };
}
```

It could be used like:

```
<!-- Div/iframe with google map -->
<div map-loaded></div>
```

Maybe Facebook API also has some simple way which you could use to force widget reload when the partial view is loaded, however I've never tried to use that with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to wrap it in a $rootScope.$apply function in order to update your view?

```
$rootScope.$apply(function () {
    // some code 
});
```